# WSO2 issue creating organization using TenantMgtAdminServiceStub

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I wrote a code that adds a tenant to WSO2 using TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.

The tenant is added successfully, however when I try to add API to it using APIM 1.10.0 CreateApi::postApis, I get an exception (all details will follow below).

Only after I login to the admin of the newly created tenant's in the publisher UI (or by curl to login.jag) I'm able to add my API using the same CreateApi::postApis.

Here are the details.

The code to add the tenant:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", clientTrustStore.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "admin");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "admin");
    System.setProperty("carbon.repo.write.mode", "true");       

    TenantMgtAdminServiceStub stub = new TenantMgtAdminServiceStub("https://localhost:9443/services/TenantMgtAdminService.TenantMgtAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/");

    ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
    setBasicAccessSecurityHeaders(adminUser, adminPasswd, sc);

    try
    {
        TenantInfoBean tenant = new TenantInfoBean();

        tenant.setActive(true);
        tenant.setAdmin("admin");
        tenant.setAdminPassword("admin");
        tenant.setTenantDomain("testing123.com");
        tenant.setFirstname("first");
        tenant.setLastname("last");
        tenant.setEmail("email@testing123.com");

        stub.addTenant(tenant);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) { ... }
    catch (TenantMgtAdminServiceExceptionException e) { ... }
    finally
    {
        stub.cleanup();
    }
```

The code that adds the API:

```
    ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
    apiClient.setBasePath("https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.9");
    apiClient.getAuthentications().put("BasicAuth", new HttpBasicAuth());
    apiClient.setUsername("admin@testing123.com");
    apiClient.setPassword("admin");
    apiClient.setDebugging(true);

    CreateApi crApi = new CreateApi(apiClient);

    API body = new API();
    ... invoke setters of body ...
    API createdApi = crApi.apisPost(body, "application/json");
    ...
```

Doing so I receive the following exception:

```
TID: [11] [] [2016-04-13 10:13:37,065] admin@testing123.com@testing123.com [11] [AM]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl} -  Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. id: b299a2ca-ae27-4198-a8dc-f69afda05379, path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin-AT-testing123.com/partnerInfo/1.0.0/api. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Couldn't find aspectName 'APILifeCycle'
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.associateAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2428)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.associateAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:458)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspectInternal(UserRegistry.java:1900)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3800(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1872)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1869)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspect(UserRegistry.java:1869)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.attachLifecycle(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:378)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:574)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:180)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now, as a workaround, I simply log into the admin of this newly created organization:

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin@testing123.com&password=admin'
```

And now when I'm trying to add API using the same code exactly, the API is added successfully.

I believe the meaningful part of the exception is:

```
{org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl} -  
    Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. 
    id: b299a2ca-ae27-4198-a8dc-f69afda05379, 
    path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin-AT-testing123.com/partnerInfo/1.0.0/api. 

{org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl}
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: 
    Couldn't find aspectName 'APILifeCycle'
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.associateAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2428)
```

Again, I did not change anything in the code to make the postApis work, only logged-in to the admin user and it resolved by itself by re-run of the same code.

I cannot tell what exactly is the root cause.

Comment: It looks like issue with tenant loading. After you have created the tenant can you login to publisher and use rest api after that? Are you experience same thing exception?

Comment: After creating the tenant I'm able to login to publisher, create API's and run them on the gateway. In addition, the code that creates API's, which did not work prior the login to the publisher, now works as well (allows me to create more API's etc... without getting this exception)

Comment: Looks like there might be need of login to the publisher once as a tenant. Anyhow it looks like a bug. You may create a issue if need in APIMANAGER jira project.